# Videos not playing in browser Troubleshooting

Tags: html, video

So, these .mp4 videos are not working.

Even when I use the video tag, or link directly to the video. They don't seem to play. They play perfectly fine in Windows Media Player (or VLC).

So I'm just wondering what is the cause for the video to not play in the browser. Thanks

Comment: Err, there's not much to post. Since I just have a link to the mp4 with an anchor tag. LOL so, it's fail on chrome really.

Comment: I think the code your trying to use would really help, I mean without that I can only ask the obvious such as is the link your using correct?

Comment: It's a link? In that case you will probably really want to prompt the end user to download it then, rather than just linking to it see below in a bit...

Answer (score 0):

Basically create this as video_download.php, then link to this page - change the path to match that of you video, then when the end user clicks on the link they should be prompted to download it as a file. Can't always rely on their system to simply open it up in their media player directly from the browser.

```
<?php
$path = "path/to/video.mp4";

$fsize = filesize($path);
$path_parts = pathinfo($path);
$ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
header("Content-type: video/mp4");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
header("Content-length: ".$fsize);
header("Cache-control: private");
echo readfile($path);
?>
```

Of course you need to save this as a PHP file!

Like I said above though, it would be better if you used the `<video>` option within HTML5 with Flash as a fallback - that way they can watch it within their web browser, which is always better and far easier!

**Update**

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
<!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
<source src="__VIDEO__.MP4" type="video/mp4" /><!-- Safari / iOS video    -->
<source src="__VIDEO__.OGV" type="video/ogg" /><!-- Firefox / Opera / Chrome10 -->
<!-- fallback to Flash: -->
    <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="__FLASH__.SWF">
        <!-- Firefox uses the `data` attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below -->
        <param name="movie" value="__FLASH__.SWF" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=__POSTER__.JPG&amp;file=__VIDEO__.MP4" />
        <!-- fallback image. note the title field below, put the title of the video there -->
        <img src="__VIDEO__.JPG" width="640" height="360" alt="__TITLE__" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
</object>
</video>
```

Comment: I actually want the video to be embedded onto the website. But the video tag is not working properly. But I really appreciate the response.

Comment: See above, and note that MP4 only works in `<video>` in Safari or iPhone or iPad, you need to use .OGV for other modern browsers....